# Read CSV file with all special characters using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a scenario to import the csv file then validate the content, I have a cell with following special characters

```
“ !#$%&’()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}”~
```

When I read the CSV file with above characters in cell using `CSV.read("csv_filepath")`, I am getting following

```
“ !\#$%&’()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}”~
```

backslash(\) is added for # and \, how to read the exact content

Comment: You probably already have the exact content. See `"\#$".length #=> 2` or `"\#$"[0] => "#"` – there's no actual backslash in the string, it's just an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) because `#` has special meaning (just like backslash itself).

Comment: The character sequence is 1 char longer after being loaded using the `#read` method (probably because of the backslash added before the initial backslash) and reading from the CSV file with the special characters and writing the result to a new CSV will keep the added characters which seems a bit odd and inconvenient

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right. The mistake was on my side, saved the array of arrays instead of just the value. Worked like expected when I did it the proper way.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, gotcha. Can I ignore the escape characters while reading the csv file

Comment: @arunkumarsambu not sure what you mean. The escape characters are not part of the string. If you need further help, please provide an example that I can copy and paste.